# Calculating F-statistic, why is SS used instead of just $r^2$?

Tags: regression, correlation, sums-of-squares, f-statistic

The calculations and question are for a simple regression (one independent and one dependent variable).

SSres = SSy * (1 - $r^2$)

SSreg = SSy * $r^2$

F = (SSreg / DFreg)/(SSres / DFres)

So, I've figured out that the value of SSy does not matter for what F-value we get, and that's a good thing since otherwise the F-value is in part contingent upon the scale of our measure. So, in actuality, am I correct to assume that we could in fact simply replace SSres and SSreg with $r^2$ and $(1 - r^2)$ and ignore the in-between calculations of SSres and SSreg? Or is this due to that the F-statistic in this case comes from a simple regression, as opposed to multiple regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could replace SSres and SSreg with $r^2$ and $(1 - r^2)$. For multiple regression, you can replace SSres and SSreg with $R^2$ and $(1 - R^2)$, where $R^2$ is (unadjusted) R square.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why SS is used in almost every single formula for F that I come across in textbooks? (Mostly undergraduate textbooks but also a couple of graduate/general textbooks for social sciences.)

Comment: Two methods give you the exact results (maybe round off difference). I have no clear idea why people use SS, instead of $r^2$ or $R^2$. My guess is: (1) in the process of computing, RRs come first, if you do not need r or R, you can get F from SS directly (it is very important in non-computer time) (2) It is easy to understand the segment of SS. (SS(total) = SS(model) + SS(left)).

Answer (score 1):

If the degrees-of-freedom are taken as fixed, the F-statistic and the coefficient of determination are related as one-to-one functions:

$$F = \frac{MS_{Reg}}{MS_{Res}} = \frac{df_{Res}}{df_{Reg}} \cdot \frac{SS_{Reg}}{SS_{Res}} = \frac{df_{Res}}{df_{Reg}} \cdot \frac{R^2}{1-R^2}.$$

If you have already calculated the coefficient of determination then you can use this to obtain the F-statistic via the above formula.  From this equation we see that these two measures of goodness-of-fit are monotonicly related (a higher coefficient of determination goes with a higher F-statistic).

Incidentally, this means that a goodness-of-fit test could just as legitimately be conducted directly on the coefficient of determination instead of the F-statistic.  The latter is generally used becuase it has a simpler distribution, but they are both increasing monotonic functions of one another, so either statistic gives a proper ordinal measure of the evidence against the null hypothesis in a goodness-of-fit test.